# Figure out if TextInput has focus via ref

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

The configuration is as follows:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     
        this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    }

    ...
 
    render() {
        ...
        <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
           ...                           
           ref={this.inputRef}
        />
        ...
    }
}
```

**Q.** How to find out if TextInput *has focus* within a *render()* method?

Answer (score 1):

you can check either by using [this functions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#isfocused) or by creating your custom setup  by registering onBlur() and onFocus() callback functions in your textInput.

e.g.

```
<TextInput
          onFocus={() =>console.log("focus received" ) }
          onBlur={() => console.log("focus lost") } />
```